# Submitting a Form in JQUERY appending different variables in URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am subitting a form using Jquery. But the form elements are getting appended to the URL.

Any idea how to prevent this feature.

## Code to submit the form

```
$("#form_chk_app_pnt_tdy").submit(function()
{
    //alert("pfo_gnCheckNumber");   

    $.ajax({
            url:'cfc/print.cfc?method=getMassChkReqIDs',
            type:'GET',
            beforeSend: function(xhr,settings)
            {
                //alert(xhr.readyState);
                //setTimeout(function (){
                    $('#dv_gnCheckNumber').hide();
                    $('#load_image').show();
                //},2000);                  
            },                              
            success:function(data,textStatus,xhr)
            {
                //alert(xhr.readyState);                    
                $('#dv_gnCheckNumber').show();
                $('#pfo_gnCheckNumber').attr('disabled','disabled');
                $('#load_image').hide();
                //$("#form_chk_app_pnt_tdy").click();   
                //(event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;              
            },              
            error:function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown)
            {
                alert(errorThrown); 
            }

         });

});
```

While submitting this form I am getting checkbox value and button value in the URL. I dont want this behaviour.

Comment: Use a type `POST`, `GET` requests are meant to be like that.

Answer (score 0):

use `POST` method.instead of using `Get`Method.